# How to solve this code?

Tags: c, input

The input description:

> Your program will be tested on one or more test cases. Each test case is made of a single positive number (0 < n0 < 1, 000, 000).
>
> The last line of the input file has a single zero (which is not part of the test cases.)

I just typed a code like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n0;

    while((scanf("%d", &n0)) != 0)
    {
    ..........
    }
```

but why when input 0 still processed?

Comment: Your title is extremely bad.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions. You need to check the value of `n0`.

Comment: I guess the pub beacons more than doing the homework where you learn something for your career!

Comment: did you read the comments you got on your previous (identical) question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614958/how-to-terminate-input-by-zero-in-c

Comment: yes, it my first post...

Comment: Well, frankly, I think that nine downvotes is more than overkill here;  on the other hand, posting what appears to be a homework problem tends to attract downvotes.  This may be discouraging; if so, please be aware that we all get our share of downvotes (and regular responders to questions tagged with `c` seem to be a bit more free with their downvotes than those who respond to other tags :-).  You got some good answers for this question - use them to learn from.  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (1) {
  scanf("%d", &n0);
  if (n0==0) break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Then you should use the accept button. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

0 is still processed because scanf's return value is the number of items that it's filled in.  In the case when your input file ends in 0, it will return 1 - not zero.

You want to detect when your value is zero and then break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect place to use one of C's seldom-remembered operators, the "," or sequencing operator.  Here's your code rewritten to make use of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
  {
  char *str[] = { "123", "456", "789", "0" };
  int i = 0;
  int n0;
  int scanret;

  while((scanret = sscanf(str[i], "%d", &n0)), n0 != 0)
    {
    printf("i = %d  n0 = %d  scanret = %d\n", i, n0, scanret);
    i += 1;
    }

    printf("i = %d  n0 = %d  scanret = %d  after loop termination\n", i, n0, scanret);
  }
```

Take a look at the condition for the `while` loop.  What happens here is that the sscanf is evaluated first, and then the test `n0 != 0` is evaluated.  Note that this is NOT an 'and' or 'or' operator (as you can determine from examining the sample output below) - the sscanf is executed, and then the result of `n0 != 0` is used as the test for the `while` loop because `while` uses the value of the last expression evaluated in its condition as the value of the condition.

If you run this you'll get output similar to:

```
i = 0  n0 = 123  scanret = 1
i = 1  n0 = 456  scanret = 1
i = 2  n0 = 789  scanret = 1
i = 3  n0 = 0    scanret = 1  after loop termination
```

Share and enjoy.